# Modify create content flow

Tags: forms

I want to do the following:

1. filling content (create new content)
2. after pressing the save button (submit) will display the contents of the data has been filled,and other additional information required
3. select save to submit the content, or cancel it

How do I show data that has been filled as a confirmation before the data saved?

I have tried using the Form API to change the flow of the process (_form_alter) but no success. And i can't find the examples to altering the content type.

Answer (score 1):

Provide the roles to user to make any content and after save the content it will show with restriction.
Or 
you can make custom module for that.

Comment: What I want is, that before we save the content, users will see a confirmation or information about data entry and other supporting information.

What I do is create a multistep form using form_alter, whereas in the second step I show entries from the first step (content type). The problem is because it uses form_alter, then the fields of the first step still displayed.

Is there any way to know the fields contained in a content type?